# Using Vue CLI - How do I update, remove and view all available plugins

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am new to **Vue.js** and it looks like **Vue CLI** is the way to go for rapid development. So I installed it and created an app which is running nicely.

I added the **Vuetify.js** plugin with `vue add vuetify` and will also add the `vuex` and `vue-router` plugins. But I was wondering about:

1. Is there a command to list all available Vue CLI plugins? I am aware that one can manually select some during the creation of an app.
2. How do I update a plugin such as Vuetify.js?
3. How do I remove a plugin from my app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for 1. :   `vue inspect --plugins`

Comment: If you are familiar with Vue CLI then you should explore Nuxt.js for even faster development

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `vue inspect --plugins`
2. Remove it and the add it again.
3. I've looked for it, and this is also ridiculous, It seems you have to do it manually, go to the src/plugins directory, and read what it's related to the plugin and remove. Maybe you could open an issue on the github repository?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1. Is there a command to list all available Vue CLI plugins?**

You can use `vue ui` command to open vue ui in browser. There import your project, than click on your added project. On left hand side you'll see "Plugins" menu (along with other useful menus). Here you can see list of all the plugins, add new plugin, update existing plugins.

Another way is to check the package.json file. Check for any dependancy with ***vue-cli-plugin-**** or ***@vue/cli-plugin-****. These are your vue plugins, because all vue cli plugin must start with **cli-plugin**.

**Q2. How do I update a plugin such as Vuetify.js?**

In the vue ui, from plugins menu you can update your plugins. If there is a newer version of any plugin, an update icon will appear on the right hand side of that plugin. Just click it and it will take care rest of the update. I've searched but couldn't find any suitable command for this. So if you want to use the command prompt, `npm update` will do the trick.

**Q3. How do I remove a plugin from my app?**

Again there is no vue command to do this. We have to fall back to npm and use `npm uninstall` instead. This will remove the plugin from your project, however vue cli plugins can modify your project. These changes you have to remove manually.

Answer (score -1):

*[This only answers 1.]*

The current answer mentions `vue inspect --plugins`, but according to the integrated help :

```sh
$ vue inspect --help
Usage: inspect [options] [paths...]

inspect the webpack config in a project with vue-cli-service
```

And indeed, on a fresh app instantiated with `vue create`, it doesn't seem to list all the available plugins.

Now, if you look at your `package.json` file, you'll notice that the plugins you selected are all called `vue-cli-plugin-xxx`.

At the time of writing, yarn doesn't seem to have a search command, but npm does, so the following command seems to be what you need :

```sh
$ npm search vue-cli-plugin
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest | unit-jest plugin…    | =akryum =soda…  | 2019-11-27 | 4.1.1    | vue cli unit-jest
vue-cli-plugin-vuetify    | Vuetify Framework…   | =amajesticpota… | 2019-11-05 | 2.0.2    | vuetify vuetify plugin vue-cli vue-cli vuetify vue-cli material vue-cli-3 vue-cli-3 vuetify vue-cli-3 material
@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypre | e2e-cypress plugin…  | =akryum =soda…  | 2019-11-27 | 4.1.1    | vue cli e2e-cypress
ss                        |                      |                 |            |          |
vue-cli-plugin-navigator  | Multi-page…          | =colorless      | 2019-12-05 | 2.1.0    | vue cli plugin pages vue-cli vue-cli-plugin dev development multi multiple homepage navigator navigation
@vue/cli-plugin-unit-moch | mocha unit testing…  | =akryum =soda…  | 2019-11-27 | 4.1.1    | vue vue-cli mocha webpack unit-testing
a                         |                      |                 |            |          |
vue-cli-plugin-vuedock    | Vue CLI 3 plugin…    | =kaizendorks    | 2019-10-29 | 1.1.0    | vue docker vue-cli vue-cli-plugin
@vue/cli-plugin-babel     | babel plugin for…    | =akryum =soda…  | 2019-11-27 | 4.1.1    | vue cli babel
vue-cli-plugin-publicpath | rewrite assets…      | =colorless      | 2019-01-15 | 1.1.1    | vue cli plugin vue-cli-plugin publicPath rewrite override
vue-cli-plugin-electron-b | A Vue Cli 3 plugin…  | =nklayman       | 2019-12-03 | 1.4.3    | electron vue cli vue-cli vue-cli-plugin webpack electron-builder electron-webpack
uilder                    |                      |                 |            |          |
vue-cli-plugin-buefy      | Vue CLI 3.x plugin…  | =anteriovieira… | 2019-07-31 | 0.3.7    | vue vue-cli plugin buefy
vue-cli-plugin-externals  | Manage external…     | =colorless      | 2019-07-08 | 2.0.2    | vue vue-cli vue-cli-plugin externals cdn-modules
vue-cli-plugin-e2e-nightw | Vue-cli 3 plugin…    | =daposy         | 2019-08-12 | 2.2.1    | vue vue-cli browserstack nightwatch nightwatch-browserstack browserstack-nightwatch vue-browserstack
atch-browserstack         |                      |                 |            |          |
@codetrial/vue-cli-plugin | Quickly build a…     | =felixpy        | 2019-04-24 | 1.1.0    | vue vue-cli vue-cli-plugin vue-cli-preset preset plugin element layout structure
-element                  |                      |                 |            |          |
vue-cli-plugin-i18n       | Vue CLI 3 plugin to… | =kazupon        | 2019-04-09 | 0.6.0    | plugin vue vue-cli vue-i18n
vue-cli-plugin-sass-resou | vue-cli plugin for…  | =undersc0pe…    | 2019-10-22 | 1.0.1    | vue vue cli vue cli plugin sass sass-resources
rces                      |                      |                 |            |          |
@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-night | e2e-nightwatch…      | =akryum =soda…  | 2019-11-27 | 4.1.1    | vue cli e2e-nightwatch
watch                     |                      |                 |            |          |
@cheap-glitch/vue-cli-plu | A tiny Vue CLI 3…    | =cheap-glitch   | 2019-12-12 | 1.0.3    | vue vue-cli vue-cli-3 vue-cli-plugin fontawesome vue-fontawesome
gin-fontawesome           |                      |                 |            |          |
vue-cli-plugin-alias      | Aliasing common…     | =berhalak       | 2019-06-18 | 1.0.6    | vue vue-cli vue-cli-plugin alias
vue-cli-plugin-vusion     | Vue CLI Plugin for…  | =rainfore       | 2019-11-25 | 0.8.5    | vue cli plugin vusion
@micro-app/plugin-vue-cli | [Plugin] adapter…    | =zyao89         | 2019-10-11 | 0.0.4    | micro micro-app plugin vue-cli
```